# Why when the "Remove" link to remove the registration type is clicked it appears the modal to remove the conference?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I have a file that has two modals, one to remove a conference other to remove a registration type type.

The issue is that when I click in the "Remove" link to open the modal to remove the registration type that has a div with id "removeRtype" the modal that appears is always the modal to remove the conference that has a div with id "removeConference".

Do you know where is the issue?

The two modals code is below.

Remove Registration type modal:

Link to open registration type modal:

```
<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
{{$rtype->name}} <a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light-gray ml-4"
    id="removeRtype"
    data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" data-modal="removeRtype" href=""><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove</a>
</label>
```

Modal to remove registration type:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="removeRtype" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" data-modal="removeRtype">Remove registration type</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <p>Remove registtration type?</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="cancel_remove" href="#"  data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary ml-2" id="confirm_remove"
                           href="{{route('rtype.remove', ['id' => $conference->id])}}">No</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="close_login_modal" class="btn btn-primary"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Link to open the modal to remove the conference:

```
@if($conference->registrations->count() == 0)
    <a  data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-outline-light-gray ml-2" id="removeConference"
        data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" href="">Remover</a>
@endif
```

Modal to remove the conference:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="removeConference" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" data-modal="removeConference">Remove conference</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <p>Remove conference?</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="cancel_remove" href="#"  data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary ml-2" id="confirm_remove"
                           href="{{route('conference.remove', ['id' => $conference->id])}}">No</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="close_login_modal" class="btn btn-primary"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you use the bootstrap modal ?

Comment: Yes, im using bootstrap.

Comment: So in the js code you have something like this `$("#removeConference").modal()`

Comment: Thanks, but before adding the removeRtype modal it was working with only the removeConference modal without $("removeConference").modal(). The issue is after add the registration type modal. When there are more than 1 modal in the same page is necessary to use $("#removeConference").modal()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this :

The first :

```
<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
    {{$rtype->name}}
    <a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light-gray ml-4" href="#removeRtype">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove
    </a>
</label>
```

The second :

```
@if($conference->registrations->count() == 0)
    <a  data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-outline-light-gray ml-2"
        href="#removeConference">Remover</a>
@endif
```

One more thing i see that you have the modal and the link with the same id, that's a problem :

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

Comment: Thanks, but like then when the page is acessed the modal to remove the registration type appears without any link is clicked.

Comment: You don't have something like this in the js code : `.modal("show");` ?

Comment: Thanks, Im using the bootstrap default js, so I just have the html.

Comment: Srry my mistake remove the js code and it will work without a problem ;)